# How can I add an event with matrix data in ode solver

Tags: r, matrix, ode, differential-equations

I have a differential equation model that is running on a network of interactions. Nodes connect to food and can take food at a rate dependent on the size of the food (see first chunk of code).

```
changes <- function(t, state_a, parameters){
      with(as.list(c(state_a, parameters)),{
        r <- rowSums(n_mat * food)
        dN <- matrix(r * state_a,3,1)
        list(c(dN))
      })
    }

food <- c(0,0.2,0.5)
n_vec <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
n_mat <- matrix(n_vec, 3 ,3)
times <- seq(0, 10, by = 1) 
state_a <- runif(3, 0, 1000)
parameters <- c(n_mat, food)
out <- ode (y  = state_a, 
            times = times, 
            func = changes, parms = parameters)
```

However, I'd like to be able to change the size of the food over time, whilst the differential equations are runnning. For example, if the food looks like the below code (where each row is a timepoint and each column is a food source). It looks like this is possible with using events in the ode solver, but I can't figure out how to do this when I have a matrix of parameters to change, rather than just a single parameter. Is there a good way to do this?

```
food <- rep(c(0,0.6,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.2), 6)
food <- matrix(food[1:30],10,3)
colnames(food) <- 1:3
rownames(food) <- 1:10
```

Below is a working example of ode events where only a single parameter is being changed:

```
derivs <- function(t, var, parms) {
  list(dvar = rep(0, 2))
}

yini <- c(v1 = 1, v2 = 2)
times <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)

eventdat <- data.frame(var = c("v1", "v2", "v2", "v1"),
                       time = c(1, 1, 5, 9) ,
                       value = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                       method = c("add", "mult", "rep", "add"))
eventdat

out <- vode(func = derivs, y = yini, times = times, parms = NULL,
            events = list(data = eventdat))
```

New, but not working code:

```
calc_food_mat <- function(t, food_df){
  return(food_df[which(food_df$time == floor(t)),2] + ((food_df[which(food_df$time == ceiling(t)),2] - food_df[which(food_df$time == floor(t)),2]) * (t - floor(t))))
}
changes <- function(t, state_a, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(t, state_a, parameters)),{
    food <- calc_food_mat(t, food_df)
    r <- rowSums((n_mat * food)[drop = FALSE])
    dN <- r * state_a
    list(c(dN))
  })
}

seasonl <- 40
foodsize <- 4000
foods <- 3
food_seq <- append(seq(foodsize/5, foodsize, foodsize/5), rev(seq(foodsize/5, foodsize, foodsize/5)))
start <- round(runif(foods, -0.5, seasonl - length(food_seq) + 0.5))
food_mat <- matrix(0, foods, seasonl)
for (i in 1:length(start)){
  food_mat[i,(start[i]+1):(start[i]+length(food_seq))] <- food_seq
}
food_mat <- data.frame(food_mat)
colnames(food_mat) <- 1:seasonl
rownames(food_mat) <- 1:foods
food_df <- food_mat %>%
  gather (key = time, value = resources)
n_vec <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
n_mat <- matrix(n_vec, 3 ,3)
times <- seq(0, 40, by = 1) 
state_a <- runif(3, 0, 1000)
parameters <- c(n_mat, food_df)
out <- ode (y  = state_a, 
            times = times, 
            func = changes, parms = parameters)
```

Comment: In the example two parameters `v1` and `v2` are changed ... so you can create your own data.frame with your three parameters and always use `rep`. This should work I think.

Comment: hi @J_F thanks for your reply! This is just an example, in my real model I have up to 50 food sources, that are all described in the food matrix (i.e. 50 columns in the matrix). So, I was wondering whether it was possible to do it without adding every one as a parameter. So just add a single parameter which has all the food values for that timepoint as a matrix of 1row x 50cols

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but are events the right way to go about this? My understanding is that events change *variables* at given time points, whereas you're changing *parameters*.

Comment: @Lyngbakr thanks for your reponse! I think that you can change parameters with events, but either way I still haven't figured out how to do it so if you could you think of an alternative solution that'd be great!

Comment: @DomBurns Why not just define a food function that takes time and node number as variables and returns corresponding parameter values? I think the point of events is because your function doesn't return new variable values, but rather tells the ODE solver how much they change. The distinction is important. (That is, your function returns `dC/dt` and not `C`.)

Comment: And this food function should be  somewhat continuous in time because the ODE solver will get upset with discontinuities. So, linear interpolation between parameter values could work.

Comment: OK, stupid question. But, when taking time as a variable what do you write to call it? Is it called 't'?

Comment: Yep, in your model above it's called `t`. It's passed as the first argument to your model. You currently don't do anything with it in your model, but you can if you like because it's there.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Lyngbakr so I still have a problem with referring to t (I think). Whenever I run the script of the adapted code (I've put it in the question edit), it doesn't work. However, if I define t then it works fine. Do you have any ideas to fix?

Comment: @DomBurns Try running this `calc_food_mat(0, food_df)`. Your food function doesn't work when `t` is zero.